# Images broken when uploading to richtext field from different browsers

Tags: image, upload, lotus-notes, xpages, rich-text-editor

I have an issue with images uploaded to a rich text field. it looks like I get different results depending on if I upload the file using pc or mac and different result if I use firefox, IE or Chrome.

I am using the standard rt editor in xpages, latest versions of all browsers, and latest version of Domino

[image]

I use the button in the richtext field to send the image to the server

the following image url gives me different results in different browsers.

http://www.intrapages.com/intratest.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-64295-Body/Image4_1350761259985.gif

Image uploaded using chrome

- Chrome: it works fine
- Firefox: get an error (see image)
- IE: no image is displayed

Image uploaded using firefox

- Firefox: it works fine
- Chrome: no image is displayed
- IE: no image is displayed

[image: Firefox]

What is going on and how can I fix this so that the image I uploaded works in all browsers.
you can try this problem out yourself if you use the blog section and add an image to a new blogentry using both firefox and chrome at this url http://demo.intrapages.com (use the demo login)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem - if you just point to the Image URL that it generates, the image itself is not available in other browsers - does it have some sort of security defined by current user's session ID? Because as soon as I clear the cache the image disappears altogether from all browsers.

Here is what I found online:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/adcf7c4dbe1b754c8525789000631691?OpenDocument

Update:

Setting store content as HTML and mime in the backend form rtf field has worked for me as defined here: http://devxpages.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/display-picture-from-rich-text-field.html. Good luck and please let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using two ritchtext controls that was displayed based on the rendered/loaded property. 
I removed one of them and added the second one to another page and it now works fine.

Comment: I am not sure how we can know this without seeing your code. Anyway glad to know that you have sorted this problem.

Comment: well, my xpage is so complex with so many dependencies like severla data sources with different parameters like scope, rendered etc so it was not really possible to share everything. I just focused on the result when writing the post. by the way My problem is actually not completely solved. there are still missing images in some cases.  but I decided to close the post iby myself because as you said, a lot of information is missing to give a good answer. thank you all for your effort

Comment: You are most welcome - did you check the store content as HTML and mime setting for your rich text field on the form, as I mentioned in my answer, that worked for me. I think your problem is still there, clear your cache and see what happens.

Comment: What version of Domino are you running, Thomas? There is a bug with images and using two CKEditors on the same page. It has been fixed with 8.5.3 FP2: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO67196

Comment: Thank you per, I am using 8.5.3 FP2. I did a lot of changes to get back on track. amoung others I now only use one rt on the same cc and I changed the document data source scope to the default instead of "request". seem to be working fine now. I will not investigare more what was the real cause of the problem. thank you for responses